# Twice differentiable functions with compact support

Tags: calculus, functions

I know there are bump functions which are infinitely differentiable (smooth) and compactly supported. For example, this function
$$\phi(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\exp(- \frac{1}{1 - x^2}), \quad  |x| < 1 \\
0 , \quad |x| \geq 1
\end{cases}$$
However, right now I only need twice differentiable functions with compact support, so I wonder if there are some "simple" functions with these properties.

Thanks!

Comment: Using Hermite-interpolation, a polynomial of degree 6 should do the job, e.g. $f(x) = x^3 \, (1-x)^3$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @gerw, but surely a polynomial would not be compactly supported (and would be infinitely differentiable).

Comment: No, you take the polynomial only on $[0,1]$ and extend the function by $0$ outside the interval.

Comment: @gerw could you provide some motivations or how you derive this as an answer? If so, I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a polynomial. If a function $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ satisfies the following equations
\begin{align*}
f(0) &= 0 \\
f'(0) &= 0 \\
f''(0) &= 0 \\
f(1) &= 0 \\
f'(1) &= 0 \\
f''(1) &= 0 \\
f(1/2) &= 1
\end{align*}
then it can be extended to $\mathbb R$ by $0$. This will give you a $C^2$-function. The last equation prevents the zero function from being a solution.

Now, you can make the ansatz $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^6 a_i \, x^i$. This leads to a linear system of equations.

Alternatively, you can simply check that $f(x) = 2^6 \, x^3 \, (1-x)^3$ is a solution of this system.

Comment: Is it possible you meant $f(x) = 2^6 x^3(1-x)^3$ (i.e. the cube going outside the parentheses)? A plot of the function you gave shows that $f'(1)\ne 0$.

Comment: Yes, thank you for spotting the mistake!