# How can we show that the Fourier transform of a $C^2_c$-function is integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral, fourier-transform

Let $d\in\mathbb N$ and $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$. If $f\in\mathcal L^1(\lambda^{\otimes d})$, then $$\hat f(y):=\frac1{(2\pi)^d}\int e^{{\rm i}\langle x,\:y\rangle}f(x)\:\lambda^{\otimes d}({\rm d}x)\;\;\;\text{for }y\in\mathbb R^d.$$

> How can we show that if $f\in C^2_c(\mathbb R^d)$, then $\hat f\in\mathcal L^1(\lambda^{\otimes d})$?

The claim is made in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/62451/91890O) (for the case $d=1$).

I'm not sure if this is the right approach, but maybe we need to apply a Taylor expansion: Let $$e_y(x):=e^{{\rm i}\langle x,\:y\rangle}\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\mathbb R^d$$ for $y\in\mathbb R^d$. Then, for every fixed $x\in\mathbb R^d$, there is a $\xi\in B_{\|x\|}(0)$ with $$e_y(x)=1+{\rm i}\langle x,y\rangle-\frac12\left|\langle x,y\rangle\right|^2\underbrace{-{\rm i}\frac16e_y(\xi)\langle x,y\rangle^3}_{=:\:R(x)}\tag2$$ and $$\left|R(x)\right|\le\left|\langle x,y\rangle\right|^3\tag3.$$

However, don't see how we can utilize this ...

Comment: Use the fact that the Fourier transform swap being regular with going fast to 0 at the infinity

Comment: @blamethelag What is the Fourier transform "swap"? Can you elaborate on your apporach?

Comment: Your claim is only true in dimension $d=1$. To prove the claim, first find out what $\widehat{\partial^\alpha f}$ is. Furthermore, note that $\widehat{\partial^\alpha f}$ is bounded (why?!).

Comment: @0xbadf00d I cannot be more precise than the last comment!

Answer (score 1):

If $f \in C^2_c(\mathbb R)$, then integrate by parts in the definition of the Fourier transform to get, for some constant $C$ which may change from line to line,
\begin{align*}
|(1+\xi^2)\widehat f(\xi)| &\le C|\widehat f(\xi) + \widehat{f''}(\xi)|\le C(\|f\|_1 + \|f''\|_1).
\end{align*}
Thus,
\begin{align*}
|\widehat f(\xi)| \le \frac{C}{1+\xi^2},
\end{align*}
which is integrable on $\mathbb R$.

For arbitrary $d\ge 1$, an analogous argument using all the second order partials of $f$ would give a bound of the form
\begin{align*}
|\widehat f(\xi_1,\dots,\xi_d)| \le \frac{C}{1+|(\xi_1,\dots,\xi_d)|^2},
\end{align*}
which is only integrable if $d=1$. I don't have a concrete counterexample for $d\ge 2$, but I suspect you might be able to make one by playing with functions that are $C^2_c$ and not $C^3_c$ [like in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357390/twice-differentiable-functions-with-compact-support).